# Found nil, after nil-check

Tags: swift

I'm getting the unexpectedly found nil error even though I'm checking for nil before using the value. Have I missed something here?

```
if self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] != nil {
    cell.distanceTextField.text = "\(self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] as! String)m"
}
```

The error is on the second line of course.

Comment: Its probably failing while force casting as `String`.

Answer (score 6):

Probably `distanceToHouseHold` is not a String, and it's failing when type casting. Try using the `if-let` check or the new `guard` check.

```
if let distance = self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] as? String {
    cell.distanceTextField.text = "\(distance)m"
}
```

Comment: Because most probably, `self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"]` is not a String, and it's not entering in the if branch.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this instead:

```
if let distance self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] as? String {
    cell.distanceTextField.text = distance + "m"
}
```

This will both check its not nil AND cast into a String

Comment: Voting to close as off topic

Comment: Flagged it, hopefully it will be closed/removed

Answer (score 0):

Use guard let

```
guard let whatever = self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] as? String else  {
  return 
} 
    cell.distanceTextField.text = whatever + "m"
}
```

If it is not working try this:

```
guard let whatever = self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"] else  {
      return 
    } 
        cell.distanceTextField.text = String(whatever) + "m"
}
```

Comment: The idea of using guard is good, but why should one use dispatch_async?

Comment: Ups, sry :D Of coures you have to use it when reloading your tableView.. I edited it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let whatValue = self.orders[indexPath.row]["distanceToHouseHold"]
println(" value is \(whatValue)");
```

This will help you see what the output. After that you can decide what's going wrong.

Cheers!!